# how to fetch post of auth follower user with including all post

Tags: laravel-5.7

how should i fetch post of user who he follows and fetch all post of database with it and give some condition like follow user post should not be fetch in all post result it should be fetch first.....

my relation:

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'follower_following', 'follower_id', 'following_id')
        ->select('id', 'uname', 'name');
}


public function posts(){
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class)
                ->orderBy('created_at');
 }
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
}
```

i have tried this :

```
1.

 $user = User::with('following.files')->get();
           return response()->json(['data' => $user], 200,[],JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

2.
$follows = Auth::user()->following->pluck('id');

$post = Posts::whereIn('user_id',$follows)
                      ->with('user')
                      ->latest()
                      ->limit(10)
                      ->get();
just getting the auth user following post what to use to get all post with following user post
```